# js ckeditor show text color

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

In the ckeditor, firstly I want to use set data that the text color is black, and than I  want  to  set text color to  be  red.

```
var editor = CKEDITOR.replace("editor");
editor.setData ('msg');
editor.addCss({body:{color:  #FF0F0D;});
```

But it does not work, what should  I do?

Answer (score 0):

Like your other question, this is very basic JavaScript and I suggest you run through some tutorials just to get you up to speed. In the CKEditor manual entry for the addCsss function, you can see that the argument for addCss is a string of CSS, but you are trying to give it something else as an argument. In JavaScript, strings are delimited with the " or ' charter.

Try `editor.addCss("body{color:#FF0F0D;}");`. Note that I encosed your CSS rule between quotes and fixed it to be valid CSS.

Manual is at  http://docs.cksource.com/ckeditor_api/symbols/CKEDITOR.editor.html#addCss

Comment: I ADD it,but it still does not work;The effect I want is that  when ckeditor loaded,it will be set some data that the text color is black ,and  then  people edit it  and  the  word inputed will be  red ,can you  have  any idea?